# i could not add horizontal scrollbar to iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am shaping a family tree using list as element to build the tree
my problem is when the get larger no horizontal scrollbar appears
I am using iframe and css to control the style of the tree

this is the style of the iframe

```
 .frame
 {
     overflow: scroll;
     width: 149px;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

and I added this attribute to the tag but it didn't work also

```
 <iframe class = "frame" width="200" height="200" scrolling="yes" src="">
 </iframe>
```

can someone help me please.

Comment: the vertical scrollbar appears but not the horizontal

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/0ojd48jr/

Comment: yes that is what happend to my .
I want to have a horizontal scrolling also not just vertical

Comment: works for me http://imgur.com/IQxwscH

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't it be

```
 <iframe class="frame" width="200" height="200" scrolling="yes" src=""></iframe>
```

to apply the .frame class to the iframe

Comment: i know that i add the class attribute when i used the css

Answer (score 0):

Please run the code and let me know where your having problem may be i am unable to understand your question

```css
 .frame
 {
     overflow: scroll;
     width: 149px;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
 <iframe width="800" height="800" scrolling="yes" src="stackoverflow.com">
 </iframe>
```